# Corona SDK: fill up a bar from left to right

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm learning Corona SDK and am new to lua as well (i mainly do ruby and some javascript).

I have a bar that i want to fill up as the user does stuff.  I've set it up as follows:

```
            --outer rectangle
    powerBar = display.newRect(210, 6, 24, 9)
    powerBar.strokeWidth = 1
    powerBar:setStrokeColor(254,203,50) 
    powerBar:setFillColor(0,0,0,0)  

            --inner rectangle which fills up
    powerBarFill = display.newRect(211,7,0,7)
    powerBarFill:setFillColor(234,183,30)
```

When the "stuff" happens, i add 1 to powerBarFill.width, which i thought would make it grow from left to right.  But, it's actually growing out from the centre, ie its x is in the centre and the width extends either side from that.

Whats the best way to keep the left side static and grow the right side?  Can i set it so that it's x position is actually on the left hand side rather than in the middle?  Seems like that might do it.

cheers in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into this problem as well when creating a progress bar. The problem is with the rect's reference point. The default reference point is in the center of an object, as you've noticed. You can use [object:setReferencePoint()](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectsetreferencepoint) to change it. I believe you want to use the `display.BottomLeftReferencePoint` value:

`powerBar:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)`

Keep in mind that you have to set this value before you set your x,y values. So in your case you'll need to set the reference point after creating the rectangle, and then assign values to  x,y again (even though you already did this in the `newRect` constructor):

```
powerBar = display.newRect(210, 6, 24, 9)
powerBar:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
powerBar.x, powerBar.y = 210, 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's width is from the X position on both sides:

1) It should start at:

```
Centre - (Width when it's full / 2)
```

2) Every frame, add:

```
incrs = 1 --Amount to increase by
width = width + incrs
x = x + incrs / 2
```

Comment: McStretch's solution would probably work best, but this solution would work on almost every platform. I'd advise accepting his though since it answers your question better.

Comment: Both are better than my temporary solution of deleting and redrawing the fill bar every time it was updated :)